# Webview not loading content when toolbar is present

Tags: android, webview, android-toolbar

I'm in the process of building an in-app browser that needs to be able to take input from an edittext in a toolbar and then after checking that the url is valid, load the given webpage. When I try this though, I run into an issue, if the toolbar is present, the webview refuses to load. When the toolbar isn't present however, the webview loads just fine.

My XML for the activity:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:paddingEnd="25dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search or enter a URL"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textUri"
        android:maxLines="1" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And the java:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

Comment: what is the parent layout of this both views? can you post whole xml file

Comment: Inside your layout xml use: Inside `<WebView android:layout_below=@+id/toolbar"..../>`

Comment: one possible solutions, you missed the internet permission  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout structure, add `layout_below` tag inside `WebView`. Your layout structure be like :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:paddingEnd="25dp">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search or enter a URL"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textUri"
    android:maxLines="1" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
/>
```

Also, add `webView.getSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` in the `Actvity`.

Answer (score 0):

*Facepalm*, I'm using a `LinearLayout` for my root element and had the orientation set to horizontal........